# SoapUI print full URL path of rest request using groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, automation, soapui, functional-testing

I'm using soapui with groovy script step
I want to print the full url of my REST request.
I tried using:

```
myFile.append(  testRunner.testCase.testSteps["My Test Name"].getProperty( "requestUri" ));
```

and I got null.

Comment: Can I suggest you `getProperty("endpoint")` instead of `getProperty( "requestUri" )`

Comment: getProperty("endpoint") will give me only small part of the url, at the same endpint u have different version of the API and i'm using different method, so i need the full URL.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to see the request info from a test step groovy script. However, the groovy script assertion has access to that information.

You can use this to easily retrieve the full endpoint:

```
def endpoint = messageExchange.getEndpoint()
```

Comment: Since it is on the assertion level of a testStep and using messageExchange. You will want to run the testStep before it can grab the full endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The below is working fine for me. you can use the same code just need to change your step name.

Note: Make sure your same Test step should have run prior to below code.else you will get the error

> [Cannot invoke method getURL() on null object], see error log for details.

**Working Code:**

```
def tr=testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("TriggerRequestTransactionsReportsService_V)
def String endPointUrlSave= tr.getHttpRequest().getResponse().getURL(); 
log.info "Your EndpointUrl is : " + endPointUrlSave;
```